# How to restore a SQL Server backup in GitHub Codespaces container?

Tags: sql-server, github, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces

I have setup a GitHub Codespaces environment that includes a SQL Server container.

Inside `/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml` i have something like this;

```yaml
# ... other containers configururation
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

The SQL Server spins-up, but I don't know how can I restore a database on that server. When I run a VS Code DevContainer locally on docker I can just copy the file to the SQL Server container with the `docker cp` command, and then run the script to restore the database from there.
But I don't know how to approach this task with Codespaces.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: This feels like the question isn't how do you restore the database on the server, but how to you get the file onto the codespaces container so that you *can* restore it.

Comment: Yes, but if there is some a workaround where I don't have to copy the file to the container it would also work for me.

Comment: The file has to be in an location accessible for the instance; on a container most of the time that means within the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [Spawn](https://spawn.cc/) (disclaimer - I'm one of the devs working on it).

Spawn lets you create "data images" which represent readonly snapshots of a database at a point in time. These can be created from backups (including SQL Server backups - [check out the docs](https://docs.spawn.cc/data-image-configuration/backup)).

Once done, you can create "data containers" which are instantly provisioned cloud-hosted copies of Spawn data images that can be consumed in any environment - including GitHub codespaces.

[We've written about how to use Spawn data containers in GitHub Codespaces here](https://docs.spawn.cc/blog/2021/08/01/spawn-and-codespaces).